# SSIS Package with Dynamically creating Excel destination is not working from SQL Server Jobs

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis-2012, sql-job

I'm currently working on a requirement to get data from sql server into Excel destination. I used the exact method from this link " https://sqljunkieshare.com/2012/02/28/how-to-create-and-map-excel-destination-dynamically-in-ssis/ "  Except the Dynamical excel sheet name (Doesn't work, so removed the dynamical sheet naming and using a static name for all excel workbook)

Condition is : To get a set of distinct ID's from a view and should create an excel sheet for each ID and load the data from the same view with the filter of respective ID from the result Set.

The package worked fine when executed from Visual Studio designer. But i'm facing an error on Excel connection when executing this package from SQL Server job.

Here is the error message :

OnError 1 - Create Excel Sheet:Error:Failed to acquire connection "ExcelDestination". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.

OnError 2 - 
GenerateExcel:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLEDB error has occured. Error Code : 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available. Source:"Microsoft Access Database Engine." Hresult: 0x80004005 Description:"C:\Excel\ID_100.xlsx' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.".

on above GenerateExcel - package name
ExcelDestination - Excel connection manager name
ID_100 - first Excel workbook name (100 is the first ID).

I tried changing the DelayValidation property to True on everything, since the File path is on my local drive i don't think drive permission is an issue.

Comment: Works in Visual Studio, doesn't work in a SQL Agent job? almost always permissions and of not that, it's usually a misunderstanding that the SQL Agent job runs on the SQL Server and sees all paths from there. So...Q1:  did you develop this on the server before deploying to SQL Aget? Q2: What account does the SQL Agent run under?

Comment: Yes SQL Agent job. 

1. Developed the package in my local machine and deployed it to the server SQL Agent.

2. In the job step properties under Packages i'm using Use windows Authentication for Log on to the Server option

Comment: Above you mention that _ the File path is on my local drive_. When you run a job in SQL Agent, it runs it on the server, which means it can't see your local drive, and even if it could, the SQL Agent account probably wouldn't have access to it. First thing to do is change the path to one that is valid on the server. Next thing to do is change the SQL Agent logon account in services.msc (on the server) to have access to it

Comment: For example if you remoted on to the server would you see the path `C:\Excel` on it? I doubt it.

Comment: For Run as i have a Proxy account which has just the SQL Server Integration Services Package

Comment: Great, i can understand what's going on wrong. let me try changing the path to some shared folder and get back to you.

Comment: Nice !!! I wasn't aware of this small thing. It's working fine now. Thanks Nick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130650/discussion-between-gopi-nath-and-nick-mcdermaid).