# SSIS Dynamical Excel destination fails due to more data being loaded

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

Follow on from this question:

[SSIS Package with Dynamically creating Excel destination is not working from SQL Server Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134496/ssis-package-with-dynamically-creating-excel-destination-is-not-working-from-sql)

I'm currently working on a requirement to get data from sql server into Excel destination. I used the exact method from this link " https://sqljunkieshare.com/2012/02/28/how-to-create-and-map-excel-destination-dynamically-in-ssis/ " Except the Dynamical excel sheet name (Doesn't work, so removed the dynamical sheet naming and using a static name for all excel workbook)

Condition is : To get a set of distinct ID's from a view and should create an excel sheet for each ID and load the data from the same view with the filter of respective ID from the result Set.

Issues is : Some ID brings more than 800k records and resulting in failure. because Excel 2007 has a limit of 653k rows. the Excel destination doesn't allow to create Excel 2010 or 2013

Expectation : Some logic to split the sheets inside the Excel workbook if the rows exceeds specified limit. else be default can create a logic to load first 500k records on first sheet then next set on another sheet.

Comment: Row limit in Excel 2007 is just over 1M, not 635k (maybe that's a limit in SSIS?)

Comment: The question is: what is the purpose of this data dump? If it is for end users to fiddle and analyse then the 'proper' solution is to use a BI tool (for example Power BI is free). If it is to transfer data to another system then use CSV instead. (PS please don't 'continue this conversation in chat' if you are not going to respond)

Comment: Sorry i didn't know that the chat is not saved anywhere to check it later and to reply. 

Purpose : End users to do analysis and lot of excel related tasks. so it's a definite Excel format.

Comment: @Tim the job always fails for ID's that has more than 650k records. Anything less than that works fine. I beleive more than 1million is applicable for Excel 2010 and 2013

Comment: Excel is a good analysis tool to a certain point. i.e. till you hit that many records. Again I would suggest that they connect directly to the database (or a copy of it) with a proper tool. I know this is not an easy undertaking because it is a business culture thing. Anyway.... why don't you try exporting as CSV instead and see if that will open in Excel

Comment: there are more than 1000 id's and i need to deliver a excel file for each ID. I don't know if this is a good practise but the reason why we do this now is due to the year end process we've been asked to help the finance team which they will take weeks to generate these many excel files

Comment: Your finance team is probably living in the dark ages but so be it. Is it acceptable to them to provide and Excel file with multiple sheets? Is it acceptable to provide them a CSV. A CSV is the simplest solution

Comment: i know, this is not a good method of handling these amount of data. But that's be it. Yes as long as I can deliver the data into excel it's fine. I have one ID which has almost 7million records. So I'm trying to build a package that can have logic like after creating the Excel file I will have SQL task to do a count on the table with the incoming ID, if it exceeds go to a DFT that can break the excel file and load if it doesn't exceed go to DFT to load the excel . 

Else I need a package that loads only 500k records when it exceeds it should create another sheet and load into it.